# How I can fix Audacious Crash on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS?

Tags: audacious

At first, the installation of Audacious 3.5.2 works pretty good but then it crashed with `signal 5 in_XReply()`

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Often crashes with programs can be hard to diagnose, as the problem may exist with the environment or the program itself. First step should be to check for known [issues](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/projects/audacious/issues) in the program in question. In order to help with troubleshooting, it may be a good idea to verify that you have all the required dependencies, as well as build the program from source and see if the newest release fixes the issue you are having.

If those do not result in your program being able to run, you can ask the developers, or clone their [repo](https://github.com/audacious-media-player/audacious) and investigate and make changes, then ask to push your changes upstream.